# How to link object with no OnoToOneRelation to the corresponding form when receiving a request.POST?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I have a model (permission) which allow a user A to give another user B some permissions, like create an event for A, in the agenda of A.
Each permission object have two foreignKey Owner (user A) and authorized_user (user B) and booleans field coresponding to the permissions. The user A can have multiple permissions linked to him.

**My problem :**
Because the owner field and the authorized user field need to be uneditable or readonly, I face some **difficulties when trying to modify the permissions**.

My html template list all the forms or the current permissions.

**My edit forms** are constitued only with the boolean permission field. Thefore, **I don't know**  **with which instance they need to be linked** when I need to save the mofication...

**models.py :**

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    authorized_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)

    can_create_event = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    can_edit_event = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

For security reasons fields **owner** and **authorized_user** need to be **non editable (or readonly)**.

**Objects creation example :**

```
    owner_user = User.obects.get(username = "User01")

    authorized_user_1 = User.obects.get(username = "User02")
    authorized_user_2 = User.obects.get(username = "User03")

    Permission.objects.create(owner = owner_user, authorized_user = authorized_user_1, 
    can_create_event=True, can_edit_event = False)
    <Permission: Permission from owner User01 linked to User02>

    Permission.objects.create(owner = owner_user, authorized_user = authorized_user_2,
    can_create_event=False, can_edit_event = True)
    <Permission: Permission from owner User01 linked to User03>
```

**forms.py :**

```
class Edit_permission_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have a views allowing the owner of the permission object to edit the boolean field.

**views.py :**

```
@login_required()
def managepermission(request):
    if request.POST:
        permission_form = Edit_permission_Form(request.POST)
        if permission_form.is_valid():
            #I don't know how to link the form to the good instance
            permission_form.save()
            return redirect('manage')

    else:
        #Get all the permission object linked to the logged user
        actual_permissions = request.user.permission_set.all()

        #Get all the username of the authorized users (to display in the template)
        authorized_user_username = [permission.user.username for permission in actual_permissions]

        #Get all the permission id 
        #to allow the owner to delete the entry by clinking on the delete link
        permission_id = [permission.id for permission in actual_permissions]

        #Generate all the forms linked to the permission objects
        perm_edit_forms = [Edit_permission_Form(instance=perm) for perm in actual_permissions]

        #Store all the data in a dict
        data = {} 
        for i in range(len(actual_permission)):
            data[authorized_user_username[i]] = {
                "perm_id" : permission_id[i],
                "form" : perm_edit_forms[i],
            }

        return render(request, 'perm/manageperm.html', {'data': data}
```

**manageperm.html :**

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}

    {{key}} <a href="/perm/delete_perm/{{value.perm_id}}">Delete</a>
    <form method="post" >
         {% csrf_token %}
         <table>
            {{value.form.as_table}}
             <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify"/></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </form>

{% endfor %}
```

So, do you have any idea on **how to link my form with the correct instance** when the views receive a POST request ?

Bonus question : How can I generate more efficiently my data dict ?